# Is binding a click event to document better than binding it to body?

Tags: jquery

The question is simply between

`$("body").click(function(e){});` vs `$(document).click(function(e){});`

which is more efficient or advisable? Or does it depend on the situation?

Honestly I have used them both interchangeably and haven't seen any differences until I got curious and asked this question here.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If the page height is smaller than the viewport height, then clicking on the viewport below the page will not trigger the `'body'` click handler, but only the `document` click handler.

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/simevidas/ZVgDC/

In the demo, try clicking on the area below the text, and you will see that only the `document` click handler executes.

Therefore, it is better to bind the handler to the Document object.

Comment: Hi, see this please `http://jsfiddle.net/ZVgDC/11/`, it only works on chrome, I tried it on firefox 15.0.1, and IE, it is not working on them.. please get me a solution.>> My requirement is to, add a listener to document, and I want to hide a div when user clicks on any object other then that div.. so If above thing work in all browser, my problem will be solved. please see in it @Šime Vidas

Answer (score 3):

Binding it to `document` seems to be the standard practice, so I would stick with that.

`document` is also [much faster](http://jsperf.com/body-vs-document).

Comment: @alex is this an accurate way of comparing document vs document.body using `on()` event delegation? http://jsperf.com/jquery-document-vs-document-body-on-event-delegation  Because I'm getting differing results if I use `body` vs. `document.body`.

Comment: @alex I thought document.body would be faster since its closer to the node but this doesn't appear to be the case, can you explain?

Comment: @timpeterson That's a valid assumption but Chrome seems to run counter to that. Could be a browser optimisation. Could also be a check for `document` explicitly while the `document.body` has to be parsed differently.

Comment: @alex document is much faster than document.body on mobile safari too, this is a troubling result since it contradicts what I've always heard about the on() method and event delegation. Though perhaps putting .click(); at the end doesn't accurately represent the intended goal since one is no longer listening for the click but instead forcing it.

Answer (score 3):

I would say it's better to bind event to document as in some cases in some browsers body may be missing.

Comment: I prefer binding event handlers to the document because you can do it before the document is ready, I like to do as much up-front as I can. It's also especially nice in single page apps, where the body may be changed out completely.

Answer (score 2):

Also the body might not cover the whole visible window (some crazy styles cause that)! I don't know if you would still get the click event in this case. So better bind it to `document`.

Answer (score 0):

I'd treat this similarly to anything else in the DOM.

If I bind to a `<table>` then it's at a higher level than the `<tr>` inside it. If I bind to the `<tr>` then it's lower than the `<table>`. This works the same way for the document(higher) and the `<body>`(lower) simply a level issue in my opinion.

So if you want to ensure that you're binding the click event to the highest element then bind to the document.