# Change image upon click, revert on click anywhere

Tags: jquery

I am trying to create a script that:

changes the image once the image is clicked,
then revert back to the original image,
whenever anywhere on the screen is clicked.

Currently, my script only changes, when the exact image is clicked.

Image that changes on Click:

```
<!-- CardStatus -->
<img src="toggle-on.png" class="img-swap"/>
```

jQuery Script to Change Image upon Click:

```
/* ToggleOn & ToggleOff */
$(function () {
    $(".img-swap").live("click", function () {
        if ($(this).attr("class") == "img-swap") {
            this.src = this.src.replace("toggle-on", "toggle-off");
        } else {
            this.src = this.src.replace("toggle-off", "toggle-on");
        }
        $(this).toggleClass("toggle-on");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a updated code with example using `.bind()` as **Joel** suggested, as he is right, it has the best support for this. If the image is click, it will swap the image, if it's clicked again, it will change back, as *well* as clicking anywhere on the body. I had to use full URLs due to the dynamic nature of image hosts, but your original replacement code should work fine.

Rather then running two functions we shrank it into one. This may not work with other `.click()` events, same with the other answers without adding the event handlers like I did in this function and stopping propigation on the `.click()` events.

```
var img = $('.img-swap'),
    imgs = new Array('http://s27.postimg.org/i6knc8y0j/img1.jpg', 'http://s12.postimg.org/k68so1del/img2.jpg'); // Off is the first image
    isOn = false;

$(document).bind("click", function(e) {

    if ( $(e.target).attr('class') == img.attr('class') ) { // Did we click on the image?

        if ( isOn == false ) {

            img.attr('src', imgs[1]);
            isOn = true;

        } else {

            img.attr('src', imgs[0]);
            isOn = false;

        }

    } else { // Nope, must be the document or something else

        if ( isOn ) {

            img.attr('src', imgs[0]);
            isOn = false;

        }

    }

});
```

## [JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/WASasquatch/xxg5A/)

This method below tries to use the dynamic element. This will not work if *multiple* cards are *flipped* at once, and only close the last clicked card.

```
var lastClick = undefined;

$(document).bind("click", function(e) {

    if ( $(e.target).attr('class') == 'img-swap' ) {

        var targetimg = $(e.target);
        lastClick = $(e.target);

        if ( targetimg.attr('src').indexOf('toggle-on') !== -1 ) {

            targetimg.attr('src', targetimg.attr('src').replace('toggle-on', 'toggle-off'));

        } else if ( targetimg.attr('src').indexOf('toggle-off') !== -1 ) {

            targetimg.attr('src', targetimg.attr('src').replace('toggle-off', 'toggle-on'));                
        }

    } else {

        if ( lastClick && lastClick.attr('src').indexOf('toggle-on') !== -1 ) {

            lastClick.attr('src', lastClick.attr('src').replace('toggle-on', 'toggle-off'));
            lastClick = undefined;


        }

    }

});
```

So you may need to close **all** of the image tags with the class `img-swap` at once if multiple cards are being flipped like this example.

```
var imageTags = $('.img-swap'),
    lastClick = undefined;

$(document).bind("click", function(e) {

    if ( $(e.target).attr('class') == 'img-swap' ) {

        var targetimg = $(e.target);
        lastClick = $(e.target);

        if ( targetimg.attr('src').indexOf('toggle-on') !== -1 ) {

            targetimg.attr('src', targetimg.attr('src').replace('toggle-on', 'toggle-off'));

        } else if ( targetimg.attr('src').indexOf('toggle-off') !== -1 ) {

            targetimg.attr('src', targetimg.attr('src').replace('toggle-off', 'toggle-on'));                
        }

    } else {

        imageTags.each(function() {

            if ( $(this).attr('src').indexOf('toggle-on') !== -1 ) {

                $(this).attr('src', $(this).attr('src').replace('toggle-on', 'toggle-off'));

            }

        });

    }

});
```

## [JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/WASasquatch/a7cBR/)

Comment: The image changes works! Thanks. However when I tried to duplicate the images, all the image changed at the same time. How might I fix this?

Comment: You'll need to use IDs, and not classes for the identifiers. Duplicating the code for each image. That would mean also, `isOn` would need to be unique for each image. You can use `.each()` to iterate through a container of all the images as well. But IDs will need to be used in this instance. Classes work for each element with that class name.

Comment: The original code worked seperatly, without using "ids" would something similar not be scriptable?

Answer (score 2):

**CHANGED** `"body"` to `document` thanks to @WASasquatch. The rationale for this can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5215117/1142167).

You can attach a reset callback to the `body.onclick` event:

```
$(".img-swap").click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation() // Stop this click from triggering the <body> click event
    /* toggle code here */
});

$(document).click(function(e) {
    /* un-toggle code here */
});
```

On a side note, `live()` is [deprecated since jQuery 1.7 and removed in 1.9](http://api.jquery.com/live/). Is there a particular reason you're using that instead of `bind()`* or `on()`**?

**`bind()` has been around since jQuery 1.0, so has overall the best support (so far).*

***`on()` is the latest event attacher, and `bind()` may be deprecated in the future. `bind()` maps to `on()` in the source anyway.*

Comment: Good point about Live and later builds, though I do notice that using `body` yields some layering issues with elements. It's better to use `$(document)`. In elaboration, at least with my webpage when I used body I was no longer able to click my normal click events as it was triggering the body click.

Comment: No problem, I updated my answer as well, since it's best to go strict, then deprecated. Haha.

Comment: Hi, I am a bit new to JavaScript, could you please help me with a JSFiddle example? or help me understand how your code works with what I have coded.

Comment: @user3556114 Look at my updated answer with example.